# llama2 multiclass multioutput training dataset preparation

Tags: multiclass-classification, llama, fine-tuning

I am trying to fine tune my dataset which is a multiclass multioutput probelm. The dataset to model is:

`a1y1 + a2y2 + a3y3 = b1*f(x1) + b2*f(x2) + b3*f(x3)`

The test data looks [image: multiclass multioutput]

Are there any python code examples specifically to fine tune LLAMA2 for multiclass multioutput datasets? There are a few examples for sentiment analysis, 20newsgroups that are binary/multiclass. But these examples are not useful for my specific use case.

I have created a preprocess pipeline with X flattened, tokenized through `tokenizer()` class and the targets multilabel() and `np.hstack()` stacked for each y class.

One problem I see with label encoding is There are over 200 classes in each Y1, Y2, Y3.. Thus label encoding complicates the problem further with sparsity.

What I am unsure is - is this the right way to do? Are there better ways? Are there are standard examples to encode this specific use case?

Any Reference python script examples, or useful data preparation templates for multiclass multioutput.